# Finding the keys in a python dictionary for intersection of elements in the corresponding dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, intersection

I have the following Python dictionary:

```
{(a,b,c): [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], (d,e,f):[(7,8,9)] ,(m, n, o): [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]}
```

I'm trying to find the keys corresponding to the intersection of the tuple elements inside the list in the following format:
For the tuple (1,2,3), the intersection should give the output as:

```
(a,b,c), (m,n,o)
```

Although it is possible to iterate over each of the tuple elements inside the list as the dictionary value and find the corresponding key, I'm looking for a pythonic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dic = {('a','b','c'): [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], ('d','e','f'):[(7,8,9)] ,('m', 'n', 'o'): [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]}
>>> [i for i in dic if (1,2,3) in dic[i]]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'o')]
>>>
```

If you don't want to iterate over, you may use `filter`

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x:(1,2,3) in dic[x],dic))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'o')]
```

If you are a fancy module lover, Use `itertools.takewhile`.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x:(1,2,3) in dic[x],dic))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'o')]
```

At the end, none of above will do things right without iterating over the collection internally/ externally. This fancy modules are kind of wrapper, do more or less the same thing under the hood.

Comment: "although it is possible to iterate over each of the tuple elements inside the list as the dictionary value and find the corresponding key, I'm looking for a pythonic way to achieve this."

Comment: @Arman, I don't think it's not a pythonic way. To me, he simply doesn't want a for/while loop, that's it.

Comment: But you iterate over each tuple elements , But OP asks for don't do this, am I wrong?

Comment: @Arman, and the other downvoter. As you don't like the above solution, the later one is for you. Though I am still stick to my opinion, that the later one is ugly and less pythonic.

Comment: That one liner could be shorter: `list(filter(lambda x: (1,2,3) in dic[x], dic))`

Comment: @DanD., yeah true. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You original dictionary has a syntax error, unless the variables a,b,c, etc. have been previously defined. But here's an answer:

```
[key for key in d if (1,2,3) in d[key]]
```

Comment: that's exactly what the OP doesn't want, cause he already tried that.

Comment: @ssj.luffy It is not clear from the original post what exactly has been tried. It is only your interpretation of OP's question. First, any list search requires iteration or recursion, even filter-based. Second, I believe the solution I proposed is the most Pythonic on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably filter() is one of the options:

```
d = {('a','b','c'): [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], ('d','e','f'):[(7,8,9)] ,('m', 'n', 'o'): [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]}

def find_keys(my_dict, value):
    l = lambda x: value in my_dict[x]
    return list(filter(l, my_dict))

result = find_keys(d, (1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you invert that dictionary of lists:

```
d = {('a','b','c'): [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], ('d','e','f'):[(7,8,9)] ,('m', 'n', 'o'): [(1, 2, 3), (7, 8, 9)]}

i = {}
for k,v in d.items():
   for e in v:
     i.setdefault(e, []).append(k)
```

The contents of `i`:

```
>>> i
{(4, 5, 6): [('a', 'b', 'c')], (7, 8, 9): [('d', 'e', 'f'), ('m', 'n', 'o')], (1, 2, 3): [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'o')]}
```

You can query for `(1,2,3)` like this:

```
>>> i[(1,2,3)]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('m', 'n', 'o')]
```

Comment: for a single query, your solution is a bit too dramatic . But, definitely it comes handy, if OP needs bunch of lookup. It does use two for loop, which has been complained by some people (Specially under my answer).  It's a lame logic nevertheless.  Overall your solution is quite nice.